# AppleScript set directory path in Finder

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

I'm trying to delete a file on my computer via AppleScript. When I apply the code below, it seems to delete the file from desktop. I'd like to delete the file in the "/Users/andrew/Documents". This is the code below which deletes the file from the desktop:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if exists file "new.mp3" then
        delete file "new.mp3"
    end if
end tell
```

This is what tried and it doesn't work:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if exists file "/Users/andrew/Documents/new.mp3" then
        delete file "/Users/andrew/Documents/new.mp3"
    end if
end tell
```

If anyone could any advice it would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `POSIX file` before the path to get a file object:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set f to POSIX file "/Users/username/Documents/new.mp3"
    if exists f then delete f
end tell
```

`system attribute "HOME"` is replaced with `/Users/username`:

```
set f to POSIX file ((system attribute "HOME") & "/Documents/new.mp3")
tell application "Finder" to if exists f then delete f
```

Or use the pre-OS X path format:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set f to "Macintosh HD:Users:username:Documents:new.mp3"
    -- set f to (path to documents folder as text) & "new.mp3"
    if exists f then delete f
end tell
```