# In Applescript, Why does my "Tell app Finder" block not delete "f" even when it exists?

Tags: applescript

This question is similar to [AppleScript set directory path in Finder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124232/applescript-set-directory-path-in-finder) but the answer there **did not** work for me!

```
local destination, libraryName, f
set destination to "/Users/bryandunphy/Music/Result"
set libraryName to "Testing"
if not ((libraryName ends with ".xml") or (libraryName ends with ".XML")) then set libraryName to libraryName & ".xml"
menuClick({"iTunes", "File", "Library", "Export Library…"})
set f to "/Users/bryandunphy/Music/Result/Testing.xml" -- (destination & "/" & libraryName) as string
tell application "Finder"
    if POSIX file f exists then
        delete f
        beep
    end if
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes" to tell its front window to set the value of its text field "Save As:" to libraryName
if switchDir(destination, "iTunes", true, true) then return destination & "/" & libraryName -- first true = click default (Save) button, last = create path if needed
```

The "if switchDir" line causes a "File Exists, Replace?" dialog to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **simplest solution is to use `alias` objects in the `"System Events"` context**:

```applescript
set f to "/Users/bryandunphy/Music/Result/Testing.xml" # sample POSIX path
tell alias f of application "System Events"
    if it exists then delete it
end tell
```

*Caveat*: This instantly *deletes* the target file instead of moving it to the *trash* folder.
To do the latter, see the `Finder`-based solution below.

In the `"System Events"` context, `alias` objects can work directly with POSIX paths, and file operations can be performed as well.

Working in the `"System Events"` context rather than the `"Finder"` context is generally preferable for performance reasons, but note that not some operations are only possible in the `"Finder"` context - moving a file to the trash instead of instantly deleting it being one example.

---

As for **why your `"Finder"`-context approach didn't work**:

The ways of the AppleScript are mysterious: `POSIX file f exists` does *not* work - it doesn't detect the file's existence - but `f as POSIX file exists` does:

```applescript
set f to "/Users/bryandunphy/Music/Result/Testing.xml" # sample POSIX path
tell application "Finder"
    if f as POSIX file exists then delete f as POSIX file
end tell
```

<sup>Another quirk: a `tell f as POSIX file ... end tell` block with `if it exists then delete it` in it - analogous to the `"System Events"` solution above - does *not* work.</sup>

Unlike the `"System Events"` solution at the top, this:

- moves the file to the *trash* instead of deleting it right away,

  - which causes the system sound for moving something to the trash to sound.
- *returns* the `file` object that was just moved to the trash (already in its new location, the trash folder).

Comment: In my case I'm deleting the file to replace it with an updated version of itself. Hence, from the user's view the file is **updated** not replaced so System Events is the correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself by combining the answers to two other "Related" questions!

the "tell block" should be replaced with

```
if f begins with "~" then tell application "System Events" to set f to ((home directory of current user) & items 2 through -1 of (get f))
tell application "System Events" to if exists disk item (POSIX file f as string) then delete disk item (POSIX file f as string)
```